# App is published but we keep developing new features. Should I use debug or release keystore to get the SHA for Google Maps Api Key?

Tags: android, google-maps

The app is in Google Play
now Im adding a new feature which requires Google Maps.
Ive never dealth with Maps.

Im reading in the documentation I need to get the SHA of the keystore,
but which keystore - a debug one or the release one?
I suppose I will be debugging and testing and working on the temporary apks while implementing the feature, so should I use the debug keystore?

On the other hand I already have a release keystore and the app is officially out there, so maybe I should use the release keystore?

I also found this command was supposed to print the sha:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

question is, if you say I should use the release keystore, should I change this word

```
androiddebugkey
```

to something else, and if yes, what to?

also, should I copy and paste it by the letter, or should I change something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need both, the debug key is for when you are building through `Eclipse/Android Studio` to test and then your release key is for when you release the app to the play store

Comment: while developing you should have a debug key. better yet create one key for both debug and release keys then you dont have to worry